# После выполнения return перейти в любую часть программы, кроме точки вызова

Tags: c, c++

Как сделать так, чтобы после выполнения `return` перейти в любую другую часть программы, вместо точки вызова функции?

Ответ даже предположить не могу :(

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это одно из безумных заданий на собеседованиях, когда предлагают сделать полную чушь и написать код, за который в жизни следует отрывать руки, вместо того, чтобы проверить реальные знания кандидата?

Как вариант, задефайнить return:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define return goto ll

void main()
{
    return;
    printf("You shouldn't see this\n");
ll:
    printf("After return\n");
}
```

Вариант второй - подменить адрес возврата, смоделировав переполнение буфера (рассказывая про стек вызовов, предлагаю этот пример студентам). Замечания: (1) работает только на 32-х битах, (2) после вывода строки программа, разумеется, рухнет. Оба недочета легко поправить, предлагаю сделать это самостоятельно.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void non_called_function()
{
    printf("You shouldn't see this\n");
}

void f()
{
    int testArray[1];
    // Замещаем адрес возврата в main адресом non_called_function
    testArray[2] = (int) non_called_function;
}

int main()
{
    f();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Может быть, это и задание с собеседования, но я увидел его в интернете и не нашел для себя ответа.

Comment: Понятно. И всё же - код программы пишется в первую очередь в расчете на человека, который будет впоследствии этот код сопровождать или использовать повторно в других проектах. Поэтому код должен быть в первую очередь понятен и предсказуем: для return это подразумевает обязательный возврат в точку вызова.

Comment: На 64-bit "You shouldn't see this" c небольшими изменениями тоже "работает", хотя шутка с \#define меня больше повеселила.

    long testArray[1]; testArray[3] = (long) non_called_function;

Для 32-бит тоже можно написать long (не проверял, но сработает). Т.о. разница между 32 и 64-бит в 1 элемент массива.

Интересно, что там еще до адреса возврата ложится в стек на 64-бит ? Из gcc -S не понял.

@northerner, а без segmentation fault слабо ?

Comment: В Linux да, можно long написать. Но с long не сработает на 64-битной винде, в отличие от Linux там модель данных LLP64, sizeof(long) = 4, хотя указатель 64-битный, поэтому придется писать long long или __int64 в зависимости от компилятора.

Comment: Тогда для переносимости можно взять  массив указателей. Но не так интересно.

--

Segmentation fault в 64-bit тоже поборол, main после non_called_function() работает.

Comment: > Интересно, что там еще до адреса возврата ложится в стек на 64-бит ?

На 64-битах GCC по умолчанию выделяет память блоками, кратными 16 байтам, таким образом, до сохраненного регистра rbp и адреса возврата влезает два элемента массива. В ассемблерном коде это можно увидеть, если забить какими-то константами testArray[0] и testArray[1].

Вроде как это поведение регулируется ключом `-mpreferred-stack-boundary`, но я не пробовал.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно, чтобы переход происходил именно по return, это одно дело. Если же просто в конце функции, то посмотрите в сторону `long_jmp`. Хотя, на самом деле, я бы такими вещами занимался в самом крайнем случае.

Comment: Да это же просто шутки (разминка для хвоста).

Comment: с помощью jmp выходить неправильно, т.к. branch predictor будет думать, что мы еще в подпрограмме

Answer (score 0):

А, если использовать безусловный переход `goto` ?